# Adding 2nd element of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, sum, element

I want to add the total stake from each list. I have been searching on here for 2 hours but can't get it:

```
inputs = []

while True:

    add_selection =raw_input("Would you like to add a selection?")
    if add_selection == "Yes":

        selection = raw_input('Horse: ')
        print selection

        stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
        print stake

        odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))
        print odds

        result = (raw_input('Result: '))
        if result == "Win":
            print stake * odds
            winnings = stake * odds
        elif result == "Lose":
            print 0
        elif result == "Refund":
            print stake

        book = raw_input('Book: ')
        print book

        my_list=[selection,stake,odds,result,book]

        **sum([my_list(1) for my_list in inputs])**

        inputs.append(my_list)



        def looks_good(inputs):
            for i in inputs:                                                
              print i
    elif add_selection == "No":
        break

    looks_good(inputs)
```

I tried the line I highlighted, it gives me an error. I thought about appending my_list with the stake + the stake from the iteration before to keep a running total of the stake but I don't know how I would do this.

Thank you!

Comment: I also thought maybe its better to use a dictionary for this and then i can somehow just add the key ?

Comment: It not clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but shouldn't it be `my_list[1]` rather than `my_list(1)`?

Comment: What is the intention of the specified line?

Comment: Yes sorry mahdi it should be square breacket.

Comment: I am trying to create a new list taking the second element of each list entered by the user for example if the user enterered [horseA, 12, 4, Win, pp] [horseB, 20, 51, Lose, bfair] then i want to add the second element of all the lists entered by the user so i can find out the total stake...i think ive probably done it a long way? Im quite new to python so srry if i didnt explain it well.

Comment: I have just tried :for my_list in inputs:
                print my_list[1] but that doesnt work as well

Comment: Ok looks like ive figured out i just done it  total_stake =[]
            for my_list in inputs:
                total_stake.append(my_list[1])
            print total_stake

Comment: If you figured out a solution, then feel free to post an answer below; it is okay to self-answer your question. Don't put the answer in your question, however.

Comment: @JJBridger - Why function is defined inside while loop?